# Getting regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How can i extract `https://domain.com/gamer?hid=.115f12756a8641` from the below string ,i.e from **url**

`rrth:'http://www.google.co',cctp:'323',url:'https://domain.com/gamer?hid=.115f12756a8641',rrth:'https://another.com'`

P.s :I am new to regular expression, I am learning .But above string seems to be formatted..so some sort of shortcut must be there.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting it from, but there are probably better ways to extract the data from this than regex. For example, the string looks very close to JSON. If you're able to reformat it slightly, you could use `json_decode()` to get all the data out into a nicely formatted array.

Answer (score 4):

If your input string is called `$str`:

```
preg_match('/url:\'(.*?)\'/', $str, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
```

`(.*?)` captures everything between `url:'` and `'` and can later be retrieved with `$matches[1]`.

The `?` is particularly important. It makes the repetition ungreedy, otherwise it would consume everything until the very last `'`.

If your actual input string contains multiple `url:'...'` section, use `preg_match_all` instead. `$matches[1]` will then be an array of all required values.

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
preg_match('/url\s*\:\s*\'([^\']+)/i',$theString,$match);
echo $match[1];//should be the url
```

How it works:

`/url\s*\:\s*`: matches `url` + [any number of spaces] + `:` (colon)+ [any number of spaces]
But we don't need this, that's where the second part comes in
`\'([^\']+)/i`: matches `'`, then the brackets (`()`) create a *group*, that will be stored separately in the `$matches` array. What will be matches is `[^']+`: Any character, except for the apostrophe (the `[]` create a character class, the `^` means: exclude these chars). So this class will match any character up to the point where it reaches the closing/delimiting apostrophe. 
`/i`: in case the string might contain `URL:'http://www.foo.bar'`, I've added that `i`, which is the case-insensitive flag.

That's about it.
[Perhaps you could sniff around here](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to get a better understanding of regex's

*note:* I've had to escape the single quotes, because the pattern string uses single quotes as delimiters: `"/url\s*\:\s*'([^']+)/i"` works just as well. If you don't know weather or not you'll be dealing with single or double quotes, you could replace the quotes with another char class:

```
preg_match('/url\s*\:\s*[\'"]([^\'"]+)/i',$string,$match);
```

Obviously, in that scenario, you'll have to escape the delimiters you've used for the pattern string...